# Precession of perihelion when a planet is tidally locked

Tags: astrophysics

When a planet is tidally locked to its sun, and its orbit is elliptical, then it seems the planet must periodically exchange some angular momentum between its orbit and its rotation around its own axis.  If so, then it also seems that the perihelion of the planet's orbit should precess, though it isn't obvious how strong the effect would be. Has this calculation been done, and has it been applied to Mercury's orbit?